# os.listdir does not work if path includes "."

Tags: python-3.x

```
def traverse_dir(path: str, allfile: list):
    filelist = os.listdir(path)
    for filename in filelist:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            traverse_dir(filepath, allfile)
        else:
            allfile.append(filepath)
    print("ok")
    return allfile


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filelists = []
    print(traverse_dir(r'H:\2021-0003\恢复提取的数据\图片文件（PNG）、电子文档（DOC、DOCX、WPS）、电子表格（XLS、XLSX、ET）\2021-0003-JC01\Partition1', filelists))
```

I have a question, when I use Python `os.listdir` with directory path, I got an error, file not found, and my file name includes "."

The error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] 系统找不到指定的路径。: 'H:\\2021-0003\\恢复提取的数据\\图片文件（PNG）、电子文档（DOC、DOCX、WPS）、电子表格（XLS、XLSX、ET）\\2021-0003-JC01\\Partition1\\Root\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Kingsoft\\WPS Cloud Files\\userdata\\qing\\filecache\\.343623948\\cachedata\\0D853AE97AA040BAA4381F40FD50701A_temp'
```

but I open the file, it exists.

Comment: Please share the code that you are using.

Comment: any file that conatians a `.` is  not a directory rather file, and a dircetory that beins with a dot is a hidden file

Comment: @anurag  def traverse_dir(path: str, allfile: list):
    filelist = os.listdir(path)
    for filename in filelist:
        filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            traverse_dir(filepath, allfile)
        else:
            allfile.append(filepath)
    print("ok")
    return allfile


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filelists = []
    print(traverse_dir(r'H:\2021-0003\恢复提取的数据\图片文件（PNG）、电子文档（DOC、DOCX、WPS）、电子表格（XLS、XLSX、ET）\2021-0003-JC01\Partition1', filelists))

Comment: @nianfouyi please edit the question to share the code, comment section is not the place to share code!

Comment: @TERMINATOR , I kown it ,but it's a directory, and it's startwith "." ! for example "filecache\\.343623948\\"

Comment: @anurag ok ,
My first time using stack over, so ,..

Comment: `0D853AE97AA040BAA4381F40FD50701A_temp` is this a file or directory? And can you open it, or does windows ask you for permission?

Comment: That file is a hidden file and that that is th reason python can see it

Comment: os.listdir does not list special paths that begin with a .

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, you may use the following code (tested on Python 3.7):

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

def traverse_dir(basep: str, allfile: list):
    # iterate over each item in the current path
    for entry in os.scandir(basep):
        # if the current item is accessible in your OS (and current item is not hidden, proceed)
        # comment out the and part if you want hidden files to be included
        if os.access(entry, os.R_OK) and not entry.name.startswith('.'):
            # if current item is a directory, perform depth first walk
            if entry.is_dir():
                #print(entry.path)
                traverse_dir(entry.path, allfile)
            # else, add name of item to our list of files
            else:
                allfile.append(entry.name)
    return allfile


def main():
    basepath = Path(r'H:\2021-0003\恢复提取的数据\图片文件（PNG）、电子文档（DOC、DOCX、WPS）、电子表格（XLS、XLSX、ET）\2021-0003-JC01\Partition1')
    filelist = []

    print(traverse_dir(basepath, filelist))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please verify if this works for you.

**Caution**: recursion will take a long time!

Comment: Thanks to [PEP-0471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)!

Comment: This is an amazing answer

Comment: Well claps to the amazing [Ben Hoyt](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir) who along with others made it possible!